# Kinect for Xbox or Kinect for PC for SLAM?

Tags: slam, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i want to buy Kinect for my SLAM project, i'm confused between PC one and Xbox one.
Which one is better in terms of range of the sensor? Does the PC one need power supply?
Need your advice.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53575/kinect-for-xbox-or-kinect-for-pc-for-slam?/) by [freadx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4069/freadx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [freadx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4069/freadx/) on 2013-01-28**:
I'm only installing ROS modules. I'm not trying using OpenNI for SLAM. Although it is one of the solution as given in this website http://www.hessmer.org/blog/2011/04/10/2d-slam-with-ros-and-kinect/  Please help with the compatibility of Asus Xtion Pro for SLAM. Thanks!

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-01-29**:
I'm not sure if I understand your issue... OpenNI is simply a way for you to get sensor data, both from the Kinect and from the Asus Xtion Pro. Once you have that, then you can think about how to use it for SLAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I am aware they are both pretty much identical if you're using OpenNI, except for this thing called near mode where Kinect for PC gives you data in the 40-300cm range instead of the 80-400cm range (as mentioned [here](http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2012/02/14/Why-the-Kinect-for-Windows-Sensor-Costs-2424999.aspx)). Both need a power supply. If you want a similar sensor that does not need a power supply, you could try the [Asus Xtion Pro](http://www.asus.com/Multimedia/Xtion_PRO/) which is OpenNI-compatible.

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2013-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-01-29**:
If you are going for the alternative, you should look for the Xtion Pro LIVE (http://www.asus.com/Multimedia/Xtion_PRO_LIVE/) since the normal Xtion Pro does not have an rgb camera.